# Signed Mails (not encrypted) with smime.p7m

Tags: c#, base64, exchangewebservices

I try to extract one ore more PDF Files from a Signed Mail. Simply i tryed to load the smime.p7m with

> mimeMessage = MimeMessage.Load(mem);
>   //mem is a MemoryStream from File created with File.WriteAllBytes(file,fileAttachment.Content); (EWS FileAttachment)

This is not working, because the File begins with:

> 0€ *†H†÷
>    €0€10  + 0€    *†H†÷
>    €$€‚
>   &Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
>       boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0024_01D432F9.7988F010"

So i removed the shit (not all here visible) before Content-Type (with IndexOf, Substring) .. now i can load it into a MineMessage. Now i try to decode the Base64 String, but if i use the decodeto Method the Filesize is nearly the Same 
but File is damaged, if i look in the Raw Data of the Original PDF File decoded by Outlook and my decoded one, they are nearly the same but in the last 10% they are different (in the original are more Linebreaks).

So i tryed to use

> Convert.FromBase64String()
>   But i get allways invalied base64 code exception

the PDF Part with header begins with:

> Content-Type: application/pdf;
>       name="DE_Windows 7_WebDAV.pdf"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>   Content-Disposition: attachment;
>       filename="WebDAV.pdf"
>
> ‚ JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb...

(before and after the , are not here visible Chars, i removed them too). If i load the base64 Code  (copy&Paste as Text, with Windows Editor) into a onlinedecoder its is decoding, if i upload the File with the base64code it fails ...
AND inside the base64 are some not base64 chars "unknown" ,"," "Uparrow Symbol", i think this will kill the decoding, the base64 code is too long for here =( (see picture)[image: base64]

But this ist 1:1 what File.WriteAllBytes(file,fileAttachment.Content); or/and fileAttachment.Load(file); saves

Can u help me please? And from where are this unknown Chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got it ... 2 Days of my Life wasted for this ***

Before saving a signed Attachment u must run this code to "unsign" and all the chars u not want are gone =)

> byte[] content = fileAttachment.Content;
>
> var signed = new SignedCms();
>
> signed.Decode(content);
>
> byte[] unsigned = signed.ContentInfo.Content;